# Setting end-points of arced arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a curved arrow that starts at one node, and ends at another. I tried to do this using the arc command, but the arc that gets drawn overlaps with the nodes it is supposed to connect. MWE and image below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, thick, fill=black!20}]
        \node[circle] (F3) at (4,6) {F3};
        \node[circle] (F2) at (4,4) {F2};
        \node[circle] (F1) at (2,4)  {F1};
        \node[diamond] (T1) at (0,4)  {T1};
        \node[circle]  (F4) at (6,4) {F4};
        \node[diamond] (T2) at (4,8) {T2};

        \foreach \from/\to in {F1/F2,F2/F3,F2/F4}
        \draw (\from)--(\to);

        \foreach \from/\to in {T1/F1,T2/F3}
        \draw[dashed] (\from)--(\to);

        \draw[->] (4,8) arc (90:180:4);

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of the problem]

What I am hoping to achieve, is that the arrow start at the 'west' point of the diamond labeled T2, and ends at the 'north' point of the diamond labeled T1. Is there a nice way to do this? Later on I also want to add an arrow from F3 to F1 using the same rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bend` keys

```
    \foreach \from/\to in {T2/T1,F3/F1}
    \draw[bend right=45] (\from.west) to (\to.north);
```

[image]